# Index out of range using lists and for loop

Tags: c#, list, indexoutofrangeexception

I have this loop here, which for each question it is supposed to create, it generates and then formats  a 'worded question' from an array of questions, such as; 'What is the sum of {0} + {1}?'. This loop then formats it, adds the worded question and the answer to an array.

```
// Use for loop to create the correct amount of questions
                for (int i = 0; i < Data.Questions.numQuestions; i++)
                {
                    Random rnd = new Random();
                    Data.Questions.Sum sum = new Data.Questions.Sum();

                // Create part one and part two of the question using random numbers
                // ex. 3 + 5
                // 3 = partOne, 5 = partTwo
                int partOne = rnd.Next(Data.Questions.Sum.min, Data.Questions.Sum.max);
                int partTwo = rnd.Next(Data.Questions.Sum.min, Data.Questions.Sum.max);

                // Randomly select one of the word questions
                string fullQuestion = Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions[rnd.Next(0, Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions.Length)];

                // Format the string with the generated numbers
                fullQuestion = string.Format(fullQuestion, partOne, partTwo);

                // Set out-of-class variables to be displayed to the user
                Data.Questions.Sum.questions[i] = fullQuestion;
                Data.Questions.Sum.answers[i] = partOne + partTwo;
            }
```

Both `Data.Questions.Sum.questions` and `Data.Questions.Sum.answers` are `List<string>`'s and `List<int>`'s.

However, when this loop is run, with i = 0, I am thrown;

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name:
>   index'

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? As far as I know lists are dynamic, and I've defined like this;

```
// Arrays containing all questions and answers
                // used to display questions and check answers
                public static List<string> questions = new List<string>();
                public static List<int> answers = new List<int>();
```

Also, to clarify, I do **not** want to use .Add(), as I have a settings panel which when you hit apply, re-runs this loop so the questions are up to date to the current settings. I need the loop to override the previous values.

Edit:
When using arrays, the better option here, I get;

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

On assigning `Data.Questions.Sum.answers[i]`, after assigning the array like so; `public static int[] answers {};`

Comment: Dont create a `Random`-instance on every iteration. Create it *once and only once* and re-use it. Otherwise you´re risking to get the same numbers again and again.

Comment: What line does it throw on, or would you like us to guess

Comment: You can't add an element to a list using an index. If you want to avoid `.Add()`. Don't know why ... You need to use an array.

If the problem is that you don't want to use `.Add()` because the method is run in different contexts, break it into two different ones.

Comment: `public static int[] answers {};` declares .... an empty array? An array is a collection with empty buckets for your items. You can't create those empty buckets just like that. you need to have them there at declaration time so that you can assign variables to them.

Comment: `public static int[] answers = new int[numberOfAnswersYoullPushIn]`

Comment: Why not simply check if the item already exists before adding?

Comment: @pijemcolu Even after declaring it as int[999] I get index out of bounds when re-assigning a variable.

Comment: There is conflict what is the type of answers is it array public static int[] answers {};  or List<>  public static List<int> answers = new List<int>();?

Comment: Did you update both questions and answers variables? you should also figure out what line of your code is throwing the exception, we're all just guessing here.

Comment: @pijemcolu Nevermind, didn't realise it was a seperate function. Everything is fixed now :)

Comment: @siroot are we sure `Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions` does have elements for sure.. else `string fullQuestion = Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions[rnd.Next(0, Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions.Length)];` will surely throw this exception

Answer (score 0):

If you can't `.Add()` in this lists - create a copy of this lists and `.Add()` there. Lists has special for that kind of thing: `new List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`

Comment: I think OP wants to add only a single item of the original list, not the entire one.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to dynamically scale the collection, but you also need to iterate over it multiple times, then you'll need to check whether it is large enough to either insert, or just update.

You can do this with an extension method such as this...

```
public static class ListExtentions
{
    public static void AddOrUpdate<T>(this List<T> that, int index, T value)
    {
        if (that.Count > index)
        {
            that[index] = value;
        }
        else
        {
            that.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

...which can then be called like this...

```
list.AddOrUpdate(index, value);
```

...however you can make things easier for yourself if you know how many questions you are going to have to start with.

If the number of questions changes when your UI changes, then you will also have to deal with the issue have scaling **down** the collection to ensure old elements are removed, which is much simpler if you just re-instantiate the collections every time you need to regenerate the questions / answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is likly to be cause of your problem,(I have asked for clarification in comments where you didn't reply).

Still putting this as an answer, as it is potential error spot and you need to fix this.

As you mentioned you are facing this exception on `i=0`. there are high chanced that this is every time case not any specific case.

If `Data.Questions.Sum.questions` is empty then, `Data.Questions.Sum.questions[i] = fullQuestion;` , will surely throw such exception. Same way for `Data.Questions.Sum.answers` too.

In such case, you must use `.Add()` to insert into list.

so your code should be,

```
if (Data.Questions.Sum.questions.Count > i)
    Data.Questions.Sum.questions[i] = fullQuestion;
else
    Data.Questions.Sum.questions.Add(fullQuestion);
```

But if they are not empty, it must not be the cause of this exception.

---

One more thing i have noticed in your code is `Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions`.

Even if you have valid list (here `Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions`) - as you have `Length` prop, it must be Array not list.

If it is empty, while doing this

```
string fullQuestion = Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions[rnd.Next(0, Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions.Length)];
```

this line will surely throw

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

as you are trying to get 0th index's data from it.

So before fetching data from list or array, first you need to check if it does have data init, and also it does have that index which you are asking.

something like

```
string fullQuestion = string.Empty;

if (Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions != null &&
    Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions.Length > 0)
{
    //here the way you are creating random number, 
    // you are assured about index is present in array.
    int indexForWordedQuestion = rnd.Next(0, Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions.Length);
    fullQuestion = Data.Questions.Sum.wordedQuestions[indexForWordedQuestion];
}
```